# building objects from json response using NSJSONSerialization

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

Using swift 1.2, xcode 6.3 and IOS 8, Im trying to build an object from a json response using NSJSONSerialization class.
the json response is:

```
[{
  "_id" : "5470def9e0c0be27780121d7",
  "imageUrl" : "https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/myapi-static\/clubs\/5470def9e0c0be27780121d7_180.png",
  "name" : "Mondo",
  "hasVip" : false,
  "location" : {
    "city" : "Madrid"
  }
}, {
  "_id" : "540b2ff281b30f3504a1c72f",
  "imageUrl" : "https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/myapi-static\/clubs\/540b2ff281b30f3504a1c72f_180.png",
  "name" : "Teatro Kapital",
  "hasVip" : false,
  "location" : {
    "address" : "Atocha, 125",
    "city" : "Madrid"
  }
}, {
  "_id" : "540cd44581b30f3504a1c73b",
  "imageUrl" : "https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/myapi-static\/clubs\/540cd44581b30f3504a1c73b_180.png",
  "name" : "Charada",
  "hasVip" : false,
  "location" : {
    "address" : "La Bola, 13",
    "city" : "Madrid"
  }
}]
```

the object class (Club.swift) with the NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData implementation is:

```
class Club: NSObject {

    var id: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    var imageUrl: String = ""
    var hasVip: Bool = false
    var desc: String = ""
    var location: [Location] = []

    init(JSONString: String) {

        super.init()

        var error : NSError?
        let JSONData = JSONString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

        let JSONDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData!, options: nil, error: &error) as! NSDictionary

        self.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(JSONDictionary as [NSObject : AnyObject])

    }

}
```

and finally the ApiClient class is

```
class ApiClient {
    func getList(completionHandler: ([JSON]) -> ()) {
        let URL = NSURL(string: "https://myapi.com/v1/clubs")
        let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)

        mutableURLRequest.setValue("Content-Type", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/json")
        mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        mutableURLRequest.setValue("Bearer R01.iNsG3xjv/r1LDkhkGOANPv53xqUFDkPM0en5LIDxx875fBjdUZLn1jtUlKVJqVjsNwDe1Oqu2WuzjpaYbiWWhw==", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
        let request = manager.request(mutableURLRequest)

        request.responseJSON { (request, response, json , error) in
            if (json != nil){
                var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
                if let data = jsonObj["hits"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{

                    var aClub : Club = Club(JSONString: data)

                    println(aClub.name)

                    completionHandler(data)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the problem is when I try to println(aClub.name) the error is

***"cannot invoke initializer for type'Club' with an argument list of type (JSONString [JSON])"***

I dont know, how could I use NSJSONSerialization class with a complex JSON response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jsonObj` would appear to be a [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) object, or something like that, which one uses in lieu of `NSJSONSerialization`, not in conjunction with it. The `data` variable is an array of `JSON` objects (i.e. it's a `[JSON]`), not a string.

But you're using Alamofire's `responseJSON` method, which does the JSON parsing for you. So you don't need to use either `NSJSONSerialization` or SwiftyJSON. It's already parsed it into an array of dictionaries.

If you want an array of `Club` objects, you could do can just iterate through this array, building `Club` objects from the dictionaries:

```
class ApiClient {
    func getList(completionHandler: ([Club]?, NSError?) -> ()) {
        let URL = NSURL(string: "https://myapi.com/v1/clubs")
        let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)

        mutableURLRequest.setValue("Content-Type", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/json")
        mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        mutableURLRequest.setValue("Bearer R01.iNsG3xjv/r1LDkhkGOANPv53xqUFDkPM0en5LIDxx875fBjdUZLn1jtUlKVJqVjsNwDe1Oqu2WuzjpaYbiWWhw==", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
        let request = manager.request(mutableURLRequest)

        request.responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
            var clubs = [Club]()
            if let arrayOfDictionaries = json as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for dictionary in arrayOfDictionaries {
                    clubs.append(Club(dictionary: dictionary))
                }
                completionHandler(clubs, nil)
            } else {
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You obviously have to change `Club` to handle the dictionary object:

```
class Club {

    var id: String!
    var name: String!
    var imageUrl: String!
    var hasVippler: Bool!
    var location: [String: String]!

    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        id         = dictionary["_id"] as? String
        name       = dictionary["name"] as? String
        imageUrl   = dictionary["imageUrl"] as? String
        hasVippler = dictionary["hasVip"] as? Bool
        location   = dictionary["location"] as? [String: String]
    }
}
```

Finally, your table view controller could call the API:

```
let apiClient = ApiClient()

var clubs: [Club]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    apiClient.getList() { clubs, error in
        if clubs != nil {
            self.clubs = clubs
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Rob, but the  "ApiClient.getList() { clubs, error in..." call gives me this error "Cannot invoke getList with the argument list of type ((_,_)->_)"

Comment: Sorry Rob, returning to this topic, the json response after the request.responseJSON is an array of **["hits"]** but the println(arrayOfDictionaries) it's empty. Please note, the JSON response I printed on top is a JSON array after the **let data = jsonObj["hits"].arrayValue as [JSON]?**, becouse in this line I extract the **["hits"]** value of the JSON response

Comment: Sorry Rob, Im not explaining well, without using swiftyjson, the json response is an array of hits, but when I try to convert it to an [string : anyObject], then arrayOfDictionaries is empty.

Comment: yes Rob you're right, even so with **[[String : AnyObject]]** the arrayOfDictionaries continues empty after the json response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76937/discussion-between-edu-and-rob).